# Debug regex mismatch

Tags: c++, regex

I want to know if there is a way to have some sort of diagnostics regarding a mismatch when using std::regex to match a std::string.

```
std::string to_match = "abc123abc123";
std::regex re("(abc)(123)(sss)123");
bool b = std::regex_match(to_match, re);
```

I want to know something about the mismatch above, for example that the mismatch occurred at character 7 in to_match.

Comment: [`regex_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) does not provide such details upon a failure.

Comment: Consider [Regex101](http://regex101.com) or some other external testing tool. Either it matches or doesn't match in the C++ version. To find out where it failed you either need to implement your own regular expression engine (super hard) or manipulate the regex string to be more generic (still hard).

Comment: What does it mean to say that the mismatch is at a particular location? That might be meaningful for a simple regexp like this, but not when you have alternatives, lookarounds, quantifiers, etc.

Comment: I can't use an external tool because I don't know the source string in advance and I don't want to validate the regex pattern, that's not the use case that I'm searching for. I'm not particularly interested in the position of the mismatch I was just giving an example of useful information that I would like to have for the example that I gave. I'm interested for diagnostics that an user may use to fix their string to match the pattern. A form of @Andreas DM answer is probably what I'll use if there isn't a better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know something about the mismatch above, for example that
>   the mismatch occurred at character 7 in to_match.

There is no utility that lets you see the mismatch of the regular expression in the standard library.
The expression matches or it does not, simple as that.

---

If you absolutely want to find where it mismatches (for simple expressions), I suppose you could go the bruteforce route

- Does `(abc)(123)(sss)123` match?
- Does `(abc)(123)(sss)12` match?
- Does `(abc)(123)(sss)1` match?
- Does `(abc)(123)(sss)` match?

Etc. But that is only one way, and it doesn't account for taking away subexpressions like

```
(abc)(123)(sss)123
     ^^^^^
  taking away that
```

And you would need to handle the parenthesis:

```
Does "(abc)(123)(sss" match?
                    ^
               ops, missing parenthesis. This will throw an exception.
```

This might work for simple expressions like the above if you handle the the expressions correctly, very error prone.

But imagine when the expressions become more complex like quantifiers, decisions, lookaround etc. Then the task will become much much more difficult.

---

I agree with the comments and suggest using an external regex tool for testing your regular expressions.